# Releasing the GIL after destroying a sub-interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter, gil

I am embedding Python 3.2 in a C++ application and I have several sub interpreters that run at various times in the programs (created by `Py_NewInterpreter`). They acquire and release the GIL at various times, but I have run into a problem when I want to destroy one of the sub interpreters.

To destroy a sub interpreter, you have to acquire the GIL. So I do this:

```
PyEval_AcquireLock(threadstate);
```

Then I destroy the interpreter with

```
Py_EndInterpreter(threadstate);
```

And you would think it would release the GIL because the thing that held it was destroyed. However, the documentation for `Py_EndInterpreter` says:

> The given thread state must be the
>   current thread state. See the
>   discussion of thread states below.
>   When the call returns, the current
>   thread state is NULL. (The global interpreter lock must be held before calling this function and is still held when it returns.)

So if I have to hold the GIL when I destroy a sub interpreter and destroying the sub interpreter sets it to NULL and I have to have the thread that acquired the GIL to release it, how do I release the GIL after destroying a sub-interpreter?

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you call `PyEval_ReleaseLock()` directly after you call `Py_EndInterpreter()`? That's what the docs tells you to do anyway. :)